# Has anyone been able to submit Swift apps to the App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have tried a number of different methods and I am still not able to submit my app written in Swift (set to target iOS 7.0) for app store review and I just wanted to confirm that no one will be able to submit swift apps until Xcode 6 is officially released.

So has anyone been able to submit their Swift app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No! No one has submitted their Swift app in the Store, because it's not officially released yet, as you yourself mentioned.

> You can begin using Swift code immediately to implement new features in your app, or enhance existing ones. New Swift code co-exists along side your existing Objective-C files in the same project, making it easy to adopt. **And when iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite are released this fall, you can submit your apps to the App Store and Mac App Store.**

From http://developer.apple.com/swift